# Internal Error happens when try to insert 5000 or 10000 in one transaction 1294474088-313147 (-1775489667)

Tags: error, user-management, insert, gack

To reproduce specific problem which occurs only when there are 50000 users on the org, we need to insert 50000 users into sandbox. When we try to do that, we receive Internal Salesforce Error issue. To replicate the issue, create an ApexClass `DataManagement`

```
public with sharing class DataManagement {
    public static void setupUsers(Integer amount, Integer offset) {
        String suffix = UserInfo.getUserName().substringAfter('@').substringAfterLast('.');
        if (suffix == 'com') {
            suffix = UserInfo.getUserName().substringBefore('@');
        }
        List users = new List();
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Chatter Free User'];
        for (Integer i = offset; i < offset + amount; i++) {
            String nick = 'u' + i;
            users.add(
                new User(
                    FirstName='Zerg' + i,
                    LastName='Rush',
                    Email='julfy@i.ua',
                    Alias=nick,
                    CommunityNickname=nick,
                    Title='ZergRush',
                    TimeZoneSidKey='Europe/Kiev',
                    LocaleSidKey='en_IE_EURO',
                    EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
                    LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                    UserName = nick + '@zerg.' + suffix,
                    ProfileId = p.Id,
                    IsActive = false
                )
            );
        }
        insert users;
    }
}
```

Go to anonymous execution window and execute the following code

```
DataManagement.setupUsers(5000, 0);
```

Eventually in some time, you will see an error

```
An internal server error occurred Error ID: 1294474088-313147 (-1775489667)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have opened a Salesforce support case and Support responded this is [a known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002RKI6QAO), however, it refers a completely different case.

Also, reducing amount of user helps to workaround this issue.

Also, the fastest way to insert 50000 user is using predefined csv file with Bulk API approach

```
      data=$(cat data/users.csv)

      username=$(sfdx force:org:display --json | jq '.result.username' -r)
      echo "Username = $username"
      echo "Last part is ${username##*.}"
      sandbox=${username##*.}
      echo "sandbox ${sandbox}"
      if [[ $sandbox == 'com' ]] 
      then
        sandbox=${username%%@*}
        echo "First part is ${sandbox}"
      fi
      domain="zerg.$sandbox"
      echo "domain is ${domain}"

      data=${data//zerg.s87/$domain}
      echo $data > us.csv
      sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -s User -f us.csv -w 500 -i Id
```